# evaluate the integral where log is the principle branch of logarithm.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\log z}{z^2-25}dz$$

where $\gamma$ parameterizes the boundary $\partial B_2(4)$ where $\log$ $z$ is the principle branch of the logarithm. Do I use Cauchy's Integral formula?

Comment: Is $\partial B_4(2)$ the ball of radius 2 centered at 4 or...?

Comment: centered at $4$, radius of $2$.

Comment: You're looking for the (Cauchy) [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), a more general result than the integral theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the radius of the ball, we don't need to worry about the singularities at $z = -5$ and $z = 0$. To that end, the only important pole is that at $z = 5$, and so with the residue theorem,

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{\log z}{z^2-25}dz = \frac{2\pi i \ln 5}{10}$$

Comment: so my $f(z):=\frac{\log z}{z+5}$?

Comment: Bingo. There you go. The Cauchy Formula is a specific case of the residue theorem.